# image is not showing in django template

Tags: python, django, image, templates

I am facing problem showing image file in the django ecommerce project.Can anyone help in this issue?

home.html

```
    {% for product in products %}
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class="thumbnail">
                {% if product.productimage_set.all %}
                        {% for item in product.productimage_set.all %}
                        <img class='img-responsive' src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image}}" />                         
                        {% endfor %}

                {% else %}
                <img class='img-responsive' src="{% static "img/placeholder.svg" %}" />
                {% endif %}

                <div class="caption">
                <a href='{{ product.get_absolute_url }}'> <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3></a>
                <p>{{ product.description|truncatewords:15}}</p>
                <p><a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                </div>
         </div>
    </div> {% endfor %}
```

model.py

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')
featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.product.title
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<img class='img-responsive' src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image.url }}" />
```

or

```
<img class='img-responsive' src="{{ item.image.url }}" />
```

and in main urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static 


urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: After modification from your suggestion still not showing the image.

Comment: <img class='img-responsive' src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image}}" />

Comment: ok can you show what url is getting posted by inspecting element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148986/discussion-between-exprator-and-jisan).